# StreamWriter Basic but error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Trying to write a series of lines to a streamwriter in ASP.NET 3.5 VB.NET but I get an error 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' Here is the code

```
Dim sW As StreamWriter, iX As Integer = 0
For iX = 0 To 5
  sW.WriteLine("SomeThing") 'Error occurs here 
Next
```

My goal is to write a write a series of strings in different lines. This seems so simple but I don't see how the reference isn't set; I'm declaring two lines above. TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It gives  error because you are not Initializing a new instance of the StreamWriter class.

Dim sW as New StreamWriter

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5f5x7kt.aspx

Answer (score 2):

sw is not initialized. That's the source of the error. You can to instantiate a streamwriter before using the variable. Example :

```
Dim sw as new StreamWriter("c:\text.txt")
```

[edit] according your comments, here another answer :

You can either concatenate strings :

```
Dim string1 as string
Dim string2 as string
Dim string3 as string

string1 = "String1"
string2 = "String2"
string3 = string1 + Environment.NewLine + string2
```

Or use the [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) class :

```
Dim sb as new StringBuilder()
Dim string3 as string

sb.AppendLine("string1")
sb.AppendLine("string2")
string3 = sb.ToString()
```

Using the stringbuilder class is required when concatenating several strings (I would say over 10 concatenation) to avoid memory assignation of each concatenation.

Comment: Perhaps I'm using the wrong thing here. I don't want to write to a file, I just need a line separated string in memory for other processing.

Answer (score 0):

In the first line you're only initializing the integer `iX`. The `StreamWriter` must be initialized as well by using something along the lines of

```
Dim sW As new StreamWriter(yourFilename)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Using writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter("myfile.txt")
    writer.Write("One ")
    writer.WriteLine("two 2")
    writer.WriteLine("Three")
End Using
```